# how to separate big and small number in an array?

Tags: statistics

i have sorted number in an array. the idea is to separate the big number and the small number. i can not find any article says the correct way to separate the number. so i make my own way.

for example: array{12, 13, 13, 15, 17, 22, 23, 25}.

now the way i separate is by the distance of each number, so the distance is {1, 0, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2}.

Then i take the biggest distance, that is 5. 5 is distance between 17 and 22, so 17 and 22 will be the separating point and result is array1 = {12, 13, 13, 15, 17} and array2= {22, 23, 25}

the problem is i can not find any references about method i used. is that valid method in math? can you give me any references of that?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By sorting the numbers in increasing order, you have found that the minimum
is 12 and the maximum is 17.

For some reason, your next step seems to be to omit the minimum and maximum
values in the sample. For most kinds of statistical analysis, I think 'throwing
out' the two extreme values would be a bad idea.

In general, a possible difficulty is that there may be some ties, so that
the minimum and/or the maximum need not be unique. For example, I'm not sure what
you would do with the dataset 10, 10 13, 15, 17 or the dataset
10, 13, 14, 17, 17.

If this is just an exercise to find the minimum and maximum of a dataset,
the first step would be to sort the data as you have done. If you have
something additional in mind, please edit that goal into your Question and leave
me a Comment.

Comment: now i am researching for plagiarism detection by "calculating" the differences of each sentences. the result of each sentences are stored in an array. the idea is "the big results are marked as suspicious sentence, the smaller are not". now i have no idea how to separate that the "big" and others that smaller. i mean i find the threshold value but all i know the threshold is based on frequency so i have no idea to solve my problem.

Comment: How about just looking carefully at the 1% or 5% with the biggest scores?

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid approach and in the direction of [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).  You are hoping to find a few clumps of your data that are more like each other than they are like the rest of the data.  You have to decide what to do when you seem to have more than two clumps, like $\{1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,17,18,20\}$.  Here it seems you want to split into three.  Other datasets will be more challenging.  Say your dataset was $\{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\}$  It is hard to figure out what to do here.  Maybe you call it all one group.  How about $\{1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,15,16,17\}$?  Does the gap of three make two groups or not?

Comment: thanks, i will learn about clustering first. you are right, when at the same distance i cannot do anything. as you can see at my comment at first answer below i am doing an research now. basically i am searching for the threshold value to separate the big and the small.

Comment: It depends on your datasets.  In some applications there are always breaks and it is easy.  The hard part then is teaching the computer what people think is easy.  In other applications the hard cases come up with some regularity.  I would suggest you look at a few dozen datasets to see what typical ones look like, write your program to categorize them, then look at a few hundred with the output of your program to see if you think it is doing the right thing.  I have not done this, so others may well have wiser advice.